# Why installed msi is not showing in program files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, windows-installer

I am generating a msi using visual studio deployment project. When i install the msi, it is not showing in program files (start-program_files) but showing in program-features installed (Control Panel)

Comment: while building the vsi project did you add project shortcut in start-program_files ?

Comment: That's interesting and all, but there's actually no question in your "question".

Comment: my question is, why it's not showing any icon or name in program files?
since it's installed :)

Comment: @GhostDeveloper nobody says an MSI package "must" install to Program Files. The installation folder can be everywhere. You should review the deployment project settings so as to know how it was configured. Certain settings matter.